# Threading a data set?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a bunch of objects.  They don't need to be sorted or ordered.  They have one method that needs to be called: myObject.update().  Eventually they will need to be removed from he container.

Right now it's single threaded and the update() method is CPU bound (no I/O).  We have a nice server with 16 "cores" (cores + HT).

What I would like do is have one container object responsible for "dishing out" objects.  And then 15 threads that ask the container for a new object when they need one.  Is this a good way to go about it?

What is a thread safe data structure to hold the objects? Or should I just make the container object responsible for not sending out the same object twice?

Comment: I think we need more context to understand what you are trying to achieve. Are objects removed by its own update method or by others? What is a whole bunch? Do you update everything only once, or in some kind of "game-loop"?

Comment: [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In java, good candidates for your problem are `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

They provide first-in-first-out functionality with an optional bound on the number of elements they hold at one time.

Alternatively, a good approach is to use an `ExecutorService`, which holds a thread pool and an internal queue for serving the threads on-demand.

Comment: +1 Just implement Runnable in MyObject and set up an ExecutorService with 16 threads (You'll need to experiment to find what number gives the best performance) in its pool then feed it a *BlockingQueue of MyObject.